# How to pass a variable to element in XDocument using vb.net

Tags: linq-to-xml, xelement

Here is my code in VB.net. It displays AB, CD, EF. How do I make a subroutine
so I can call like: `Sub-name(field65, field547, field66)`?

```
Sub main()
    Dim fileName As String = "C:\AAA\test5.xml"
    Dim root As XElement = XDocument.Load(fileName).Root
    Dim a = root.<field65>.Value
    Dim b = root.<field547>.Value
    Dim c = root.<field66>.Value
    Console.WriteLine(a)
    Console.WriteLine(b)
    Console.WriteLine(c)
    Console.WriteLine("Please Press any key to continue!")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Foo(ByVal name1 As String, ByVal name2 As String, ByVal name3 As String)
    Dim fileName As String = "C:\AAA\test5.xml"
    Dim root As XElement = XDocument.Load(fileName).Root
    Dim a = root.Element(name1).Value
    Dim b = root.Element(name2).Value
    Dim c = root.Element(name3).Value
    Console.WriteLine(a)
    Console.WriteLine(b)
    Console.WriteLine(c)
    Console.WriteLine("Please Press any key to continue!")
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

should do, you can then call `Foo("field65", "field547", "field547")`.

But using

```
Sub Foo(ByVal name1 As XName, ByVal name2 As XName, ByVal name3 As XName)
    Dim fileName As String = "C:\AAA\test5.xml"
    Dim root As XElement = XDocument.Load(fileName).Root
    Dim a = root.Element(name1).Value
    Dim b = root.Element(name2).Value
    Dim c = root.Element(name3).Value
    Console.WriteLine(a)
    Console.WriteLine(b)
    Console.WriteLine(c)
    Console.WriteLine("Please Press any key to continue!")
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

is nicer and works with namespaces to.